# I'm having an issue with Blitz3D. The function "CreateWindow" cannot be found. I'm not sure why this is occuring as I am using an open source project

Tags: blitz3d

This is a portion of the code for the application below. Blitz3D is stating that the CreateWindow, CreatePanel, and SetPanelImage functions do not exist. Am I missing a library or something?

```
Global ResWidth% = 910
Global ResHeight% = 660
Global VersionNumber$ = "1.5"

Loadingwindow=CreateWindow("", GraphicsWidth()/2-160,GraphicsHeight()/2-120,320,260,winhandle,8)
panelloading = CreatePanel(0,0,320,260,Loadingwindow,0)
SetPanelImage(panelloading,"Assets\map_logo.png")

; create a window to put the toolbar in
WinHandle=CreateWindow("Map Creator SCPCBR v"+VersionNumber,GraphicsWidth()/2-ResWidth/2, GraphicsHeight()/2-ResHeight/2,ResWidth,ResHeight,0, 13) 
Global MainHwnd = GetActiveWindow();User32.dll
HideGadget WinHandle
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different versions of BlitzBasic which you have to distinguish:

- [Blitz3D](https://github.com/blitz-research/blitz3d)
- [BlitzPlus](https://github.com/blitz-research/blitzplus)

*Blitz3D* supports many functions for 3D game development. *BlitzPlus* provides many functions for GUI design. However, there is no BlitzBasic version which supports *both* features at the same time.

In any case, you have three options:

- "I don't need 3D features": use BlitzPlus instead of Blitz3D to compile your program
- "I need 3D features, but my GUI does not have to look like Windows style": use a community plugin for Blitz3D to create GUI elements (e. g. [Draw3D](https://www.blitzcoder.org/forum/topic.php?id=340))
- "I need 3D features and Windows like GUI elements": Implement your game menu(s) in BlitzPlus and the actual game in Blitz3D